# scdaemon/gpg doesn't work

Tags: gpg

I am trying to setup my Nitrokey (GPG usb Smartcard). I got it to work by adding reader-port into the scdaemon config file. I had to do this because my laptop has *multiple built in smartcard readers*. It seems to work if the Nitrokey is plugged in at boot. If it isn't I need to restart `pcscd` manually.

It seems that even though the reader-port is defined in the config it only works if the nitrokey is the first reader (`pcsc_scan -n`).

How could I debug this? It should detect the smartcard after boot (even if it's not the first reader) without manually restarting any services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit it's more a work-around than a clean solution but you can use a udev rule for restarting `pcscd`.

I have a similar problem with `scdaemon`. I use udev to restart `scdaemon` on plugging in a smartcard reader by adding this to the udev rule:

```
RUN+="/usr/bin/killall -9 scdaemon"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use this udev rule: https://www.nitrokey.com/sites/default/files/40-nitrokey.rules and also read about this: http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.ch/2010/09/pcscd-auto-start.html I would really like to use something like that. but don't know how. The original udev rules file is a dead link and I don't understand it well enough to build something similiar. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Accepted because adding `RUN+="/usr/sbin/service pcscd restart"` worked. Not very clean but works until I find something better.